# Assistance needed with array loop - java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

For this assignment, I am unable to get the last method to loop again and find the next largest element in the series of random numbers. Some input to solve this problem would be great. Thank you.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] array = randomIntArray (10);   
    sortArray (array);

}

  public static int randomInt (int low, int high){ // Create a serie of random numbers
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        x = (int)(Math.random ()* (high - low) +low);

    }  
    return x;

}
public static int[] randomIntArray (int n) { // Size of array
    int[] a = new int [n];
    for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
        a[i] = randomInt (-5, 15);
    }
    return a;
}

public static int indexOfMaxInRange (int[] a, int low , int high){

    int index = low;
    for (int i = low +1; i < high; i++){
        if (a[i] > a[index]){ // If the position of i is greater than index
            index = i; // then index will equal that position with the highest element
        }         
    }  
  return index;


}
public static int swapElement (int []a, int index , int i){
    int tmp =0;

  for(i = 0; i < (a.length); i++) {
    tmp = index;
     a[i]= a[tmp] ;
  } 
    return a[tmp] ;
}

public static void sortArray (int[] array){ //The sortArray calls the indexOfMaxInRange to get the index of the largest element, then uses swapElement to swap that index's position to position a[i].

    for (int b= 0; b <array.length; b++){ 
    System.out.println (array[b]+"\t"+ b); // Print out original list of random numbers
    }
    System.out.println ();

    for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++){    
    int index = indexOfMaxInRange (array, 0, 10 );
    int sort = swapElement (array, index, 0);

    System.out.println (sort+"\t"+ i);      
    }

}
```

Comment: Please spell out your intended `sortArray` algorithm. Is it your version of *bubble*?

Comment: The sortArray calls the indexOfMaxInRange to get the index of the largest element, then uses swapElement to swap that index's position to position a[i].

Comment: OK. Now go back to your code and see what elements you are **actually** swapping.  Also you're looking for Max always on the **same** rage. After you already swapped `a[i]` with `a[index]` where do you need to start your new range at?

Comment: my new range will now have to go from 1 -9, then 2- 9 and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like homework, since sorting an array is handled by umpteen available libraries, so I am going to try to give hints rather than a full answer.

Your randomInt function does 10 times more work than it needs to.  This won't change the behavior of your program but it's a waste.

Your swapElement function doesn't look at all right.  You don't need to return anything, and you don't need to loop.  Just swap the elements in positions "index" and "i".  Maybe call the arguments "a" and "b" or "pos1" and "pos2" to be less confusing.

Inside sortArray, after you find the largest element and put it in position 0, you need to keep going and find the 2nd largest element and put it in position 1, and so forth.  You will need to have a loop for this.  You have the pieces almost ready.  Hint: you can find the 2nd largest element, after you've put the largest one in position 0, by finding the largest remaining element (i.e. call indexOfMaxInRange but pass 1 as the start position).

Comment: Thank you jfrank, your hint helped alot.

Comment: Alright I am so sorry but, after an hour trying to figure this out I am still could not get it to work. I have fixed the swapElement and is now trying to get it to loop once more. In the sortArray, would I create another loop and run the IndexOfMaxInRange, whereas now it would start at 1?

Comment: Yes.  In sortArray, you need a loop to call indexOfMaxInRange followed by swapElement, so that you find the largest item and put it in position 0, then the 2nd largest and put in in position 1, then the 3rd largest into position 2, etc until you have the whole array sorted.

Comment: .. I gives up, it is probably so simple thhat I can't even spot it. Been on this all day and I still couldn't get it to work. Below are the three methods I made changes too. Sorry the more I look at them the more clueless I gets.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to the last 3 methods

```
public static int indexOfMaxInRange (int[] a, int low , int high){

    int index = low;
    for (int i = low +1; i < a.length; i++){
        if (a[i] > a[index]){ // If the position of i is greater than index
            index = i; // then index will equal that position with the highest element
        }         

    }  
  return index;


}
public static void swapElement (int []a, int index , int i){
    int pos2;        
    pos2 = index;
     a[i]= a[pos2];  

     System.out.println (a[i]+"\t"+ index);     
}

public static void sortArray (int[] array){ 
    for (int b= 0; b <array.length; b++){ 
    System.out.println (array[b]+"\t"+ b);
    } 
    System.out.println ("Number in order");     


    for (int i = 0; i <array.length-1; i++){    
    int index = indexOfMaxInRange (array, i, 10 );
    swapElement (array, index,i );
    }

}
```